# How to copy content from .repo/manifests during repo sync?

Tags: android, git, gerrit, yocto, repo

According to the [repo Manifest Format](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/HEAD/docs/manifest-format.md) document:

> The basic structure of a manifest is a bare Git repository holding a single default.xml XML file in the top level directory.

That statement doesn't say that the manifest (or repository) is restricted to holding ONLY a default.xml file, and nothing else. It sounds like other files can be added to the repository.

I use 'repo sync' to checkout several Git repositories. I have a 'copyfile' element in my default.xml file, which successfully copies an 'export' file from one of my repositories into the top-level directory.

I want to put a README file in .repo/manifests, the same directory (and therefore repository) as default.xml. This is successful.

But I also want to copy the README file from .repo/manifests to the top-level directory, similar to what the 'copyfile' element does. This has not been successful.

Actual directory structure after 'repo init':

```
top-level-directory
└── .repo
    └── manifests
        ├── default.xml
        └── README.md
```

Desired directory structure after 'repo sync':

```
top-level-directory
├── export
├── .repo
│   └── manifests
│       ├── default.xml
│       └── README.md
├── layers
├── README.md <-- This is what I want to add
└── ...
```

After a lot of experimenting, I decided it couldn't be done. The closest I got to success was adding the Git repository for the manifest to default.xml, as a project, and then adding a linkfile element to provide a symbolic link to the README. That made the top-level structure:

```
top-level-directory
│── copy_of_manifests
│   ├── default.xml
│   └── README.md
├── export
├── .repo
│   └── manifests
│       ├── default.xml
│       └── README.md
├── layers
├── README.md -> copy_of_manifests/README.md
└── ...
```

The redundancy only replaced one problem with another. Not worth the trouble.